# How to create a color gradient for html tags in R?

Tags: html, r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osCO4.png)The below code is meant to create 2 gradients for each column of my data. One from red to white for 100.8 to 0 and another from green to white for -100.8 to 0. The attached picture is what is generated. Much thanks!

structure(list(RFD.Diff = c(8.4, 56.6, -36.3, 26, -15.9, -8.1,
35.3, 66.8, 100.8, -20.2, 63.6, -9.7, -24.8, -4.6, 11.6, 21.3,
9.1, -0.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

```
  #Create tags and specify color gradient parameters

`add_cyl_color2 <- function(RFD.Diff){
  # Define color values
  red_val <- "#FF0000"
  white_val <- "#FFFFFF"
  green_val <- "#00FF00"
  # Calculate color gradient based on RFD.Diff value
  if (RFD.Diff >= 0) {
  color_val <- paste0(
  "background: linear-gradient(to right, ", 
  red_val, " ", round((100.8 - RFD.Diff) / 100.8 * 100), "%, ", 
  white_val, " ", round(RFD.Diff / 100.8 * 100), "%); color: #000000;"
  )
  } else {
  color_val <- paste0(
 "background: linear-gradient(to right, ", 
  white_val, " ", round((100.8 + RFD.Diff) / 100.8 * 100), "%, ", 
  green_val, " ", round(-RFD.Diff / 100.8 * 100), "%); color: #000000;"
  )
  }
  # Create HTML div element with color-coded RFD.Diff value
  div_out <- htmltools::div(
  style = paste(
 "display: inline-block; padding: 10px 30px; border-radius: 8px; font-weight: 1000; font-          size: 15px;",
      color_val
    ),
    paste(RFD.Diff)
  )
  as.character(div_out) %>% gt::html()
  }
```

,    `

```
  # {gt} table

  data %>% 
  mutate(RFD.Diff = purrr::map(RFD.Diff, add_cyl_color2)) %>% 
  gt() %>%
  cols_label(
  RFD.Diff = md("Braking RFD"),
  ) %>%
  tab_style(
  cell_text(align = "center"),
  locations = cells_body(
  columns = everything(),
  rows = everything()
  )
  )%>%
  tab_style(
  cell_borders(
  sides = c("all"),
  style = "hidden"
  ),
  locations = cells_body(
  columns = everything(),
  rows = everything()
  )
  )%>%
  opt_align_table_header(align = "left")%>%
  cols_width(
  RFD.Diff ~ px(100))
```

Comment: Can you make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @jrcalabrese data and table code are added!